# tvos elevate collection view cell on focus

Tags: uicollectionview, swift3, scale, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I want to increase the size of an UICollectionViewCell focused inside the collection view.

How can I increase the size of an UICollectionViewCell when it's focused? I couldn't do it with CGAffine, I tried this:

```
cellChosen.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
```

but it didn't work. Did I do it wrongly?

There is also an effect on the UIImageView called adjustImageWhenAncestorFocused that is quite cool. Is it possible to use it on the cell ?

IMPORTANT: I'm using swift 3 and the cell has an UILabel and a UIImageView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use transform in **didUpdateFocusInContext**. For example

```
- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    if (self.focused)
    {
        // Apply focused appearence,
        // e.g scale both of them using transform or apply background color 
    }
    else
    {
       // Apply normal appearance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add collection view delegate that avoid focus collectionview

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canFocusItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

override **UIFocusEnvironment** in UICollectionViewCell

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({

        if self.focused 
        {
          // Apply focused appearence
        } 
        else 
        {
          // Apply normal appearance
        }


    }, completion: nil)
}
```

For transition. add these lines on **UICollectionViewCell**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
    imageView.clipsToBounds = false
    label.alpha = 0.0
}
```